# CurrentLocation is nil after the user accepts location prompt

Tags: swiftui, core-location

I have an app that displays nearby performances of shows. A List on the View is populated via an API call when the app loads.

When I call my model to load my performances, I surround it with a location manager call like this:

```
LocationManager.sharedInstance.runLocationBlock {                                
  var currentLocation: CLLocation!
  if(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse){
    currentLocation = locManager.location
    //call the API
    SessionManager.manager.request(url).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
      //load objects then call the callback which ultimately populates the View...
      callback()      
    }}
  }
}
```

The issue is that the app blows up when it hits currentLocation - saying it's null. It breaks even if I surround it with a CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse if statement.  Note the NEXT time I load the app everything works great and it knows the current location.

My thinking is that the authorization has been given, but the device hasn't had the time it needs to load the location(?)

Cruising around the internet, it says the safest place to stick a "callback" is in the location manager class' (_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) func.

I get that, but how do I make a call back to my API call in that func? It's in a different model class. Or is there an altogether better way to do this. I even tried adding a sleep function to give the device some time.

Ultimately, I want the app to:

- Prompt the user for location permissions
- Use those permissions to get a lat/lng
- Make the async API call using the coordinates and get the performances
- Return the performances to the user

...right now it dies when the app loads b/c the current location is nil.

Here's my location manager for reference...

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    static let sharedInstance = LocationManager()
    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private let operationQueue = OperationQueue()

    override init(){
        super.init()
        operationQueue.isSuspended = true
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if(status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse){
            self.operationQueue.isSuspended = false            
        }else if(status == .denied){
            self.operationQueue.cancelAllOperations()
        }
    }
    
    func runLocationBlock(callback: @escaping () -> ()){

        let authState = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

        if(authState == .authorizedAlways || authState == .authorizedWhenInUse){
            self.operationQueue.isSuspended = false
        }else{
            //Request permission
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

        let block = { callback() }

        self.operationQueue.addOperation(block)
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`, nor the `didUpdateLocations` delegate callback which is where you can get the current `CLLocation`?

Comment: You are force unwrapping `currentLocation` and try to use it without instantiating it. Which crashes your code. If you remove `!` from declaration, Xcode will walk you through it.